# How to disable daily run output email?

Tags: freebsd

How to disable daily run output email from "Charlie &"?

Googled couple of pages, but there is no clear answer.

I use `ssmtp` instead of `sendmail`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a read through [`man periodic`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=periodic&sektion=8) and look for all the bits that mention `output`

Create a file `/etc/periodic.conf` if one doesn't already exist and set the `*_output` variables from `/etc/defaults/periodic.conf` to a log file. That is any path starting with a `/`, instead of a user account which is a plain word.

```
$ grep _output= /etc/defaults/periodic.conf
daily_output="root"                                     # user or /file
daily_status_security_output="root"                     # user or /file
weekly_output="root"                                    # user or /file
monthly_output="root"                                   # user or /file
```

Syslog should already be setup for `/var/log/daily.log`, `/var/log/weekly.log` and `/var/log/monthly.log`.

I'm a bit pedantic about my logging and use `/var/log/periodic.$(date +%Y%m%d).<type>.log`

`<type>` being `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly`, `security`.

Comment: What file should I specify for security_output? /var/log/security?

Comment: or `/var/log/daily.log` whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable most of the tests by toggling the `_enable` flag in `/etc/periodic.conf`

for example:
`daily_status_mailq_enable="NO"`

setting `daily_output="/dev/null"` will stop you from getting the emails, although as mentioned above, you may wish to log it to a file instead, since the reports can contain useful information.